# How can I simultaneously, and proportionately, change different typefaces' size?

Tags: microsoft-word

Pls see the GIF below. I commenced the green text at 35, and red at 20. Proportionality requires that after any increase or decrease of the typefaces' sizes, I must still be able to retrograss to 35:20.

But as you can see, after I click the "Increase Font Size" or "Decrease Font Size" buttons, the text never retrogresses to 35:20. [This appears outdated](https://superuser.com/q/166955).

***Can you please make my GIF show up in line? Thanks.***

https://gfycat.com/redcircularaplomadofalcon
https://i.imgur.com/rlObORd.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The increase or decrease of font sizes are based on the default size defined in MS Word not the font size you set it up (unless the font size is/was among the default - in your case 35 is not a default size). When you click to increase the font:

- The texts with font size 35 increases to 36. If you keep increasing, it goes to 48, then 72, 80, etc.
- The texts with font size 20 increases to 22. If you keep increasing, it goes to 24, then 26, 28, etc.

When you decides to decrease:

- 1st step (your texts whose font size grew from 35 increases to 72): The font size will decrease to 48. If you keep decreasing, it goes to 36, then 28, 26, etc.
- 2nd step (your texts whose font size grew from 20 increases to 26): The font size will decrease to 24. If you keep decreasing, it goes to 22, then 20, 18, etc.

You will not reach 35 (for the 1st step/text) as it is not listed among default font sizes but 36. While the 2nd text can reach 20.

Comment: Thanks. I added two links to my .gif in my post. does my .gif change your answer?

Comment: @USTopic The GIFs don't change my answer.